# Recalculate Total after Order place

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order, totals

I m trying to recalculate magento total using magento event observer after placing order.I m use below code to calculate total.

Observer Functon

```
public function recalculateTotal($observer)
{
    //var_dump($observer->getOrder()->getData());exit;
    $orderModel = $observer->getOrder();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
    $saveModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderModel->getId());
    $saveModel->setSurcharge(10);
    $saveModel->setBaseSurcharge(10);
    $saveModel->collectTotals();
    $saveModel->save();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($orderModel->getData());echo "</pre>";exit;
}
```

Event

```
     <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
              <observers>
                <order_surcharge_display>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>surcharge/observer</class>
                  <method>recalculateTotal</method>
                </order_surcharge_display>
              </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
      </events>
    </global>
```

But this is not working Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all order totals directly in your method:

```
$orderModel = $observer->getOrder();
$orderModel->setSurchargeAmount(10); // usually all totals has "amount" suffix
$orderModel->setBaseSurchargeAmount(10);
$orderModel->setGrandTotal($orderModel->getGrandTotal() + 10);
$orderModel->setBaseGrandTotal($orderModel->getBaseGrandTotal() + 10);
try {
    $orderModel->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($orderModel->getData());
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes we can this but this is not ideal way to change grandtotal like this may be magento has good way to do this.

Comment: Good way is convert the quote to the order. In other way you should calculate base totals in your code.